# Difficulty removing lines from a text file in Java

Tags: java, file

```
String id = filedda.getText();
String pass= filedda1.getText();
try {
    File inputFile = new File("E:/yoo.txt");
    File tempfile = new File("E:/mytempfile.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempfile));

    String CurrentLine;

    while((CurrentLine = reader.readLine())!=null){
        if(CurrentLine.contains(id+pass)){
            CurrentLine= CurrentLine.replace(id+pass, "");

        }
        writer.write(CurrentLine);
        reader.close();
        writer.close();


        inputFile.delete();
        tempfile.renameTo(inputFile);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I am wanting it to do is: It will delete string which is id+pass from a file.

it is doing correctly if the scenario is like,

```
abc
cde
```

And my `id+pass= cde`

File output: `abc`

But if the `id+pass= abc`, then the whole file output becomes nothing.

Comment: You're closing the streams with every line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only close the files after the while loop:

```
while(){
//...
}
reader.close();
writer.close();
```

Comment: Just did that, still nothing. 
it was a major problem and still there is another I guess.

Comment: @user3420043 please tell me that you didn't keep these in the while `inputFile.delete(); tempfile.renameTo(inputFile);`.

Comment: I didn't keep these in the while

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the files early.
Close here :

```
   }
        reader.close();
        writer.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Also if You are working on `Swing`, make sure its [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) safe.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `FileWriter` you should be providing true as a parameter to indicate you wish to append data.
[Shown here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

e.g:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempfile, true));
```

If I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
String id = filedda.getText();
        String pass= filedda1.getText();
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("E:/yoo.txt");
            File tempfile = new File("E:/mytempfile.txt");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempfile));

            String CurrentLine;

            while((CurrentLine = reader.readLine())!=null){
                if(CurrentLine.contains(id+pass)){
                    CurrentLine= CurrentLine.replace(id+pass, "");

                }

            }
                writer.write(CurrentLine);
                reader.close();
                writer.close();


                inputFile.delete();
                tempfile.renameTo(inputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```